# Add home page banner in zen cart template

Tags: zen-cart

I have created my custom template. Now I want to add a banner in the home page. For that I joined the code in the html_header.php and I want to add the java script file and link it to the file. I followed the instruction and add the file in a jScript folder in my custom template. Now I added my css file to the css folder but I can't get where to link  those files.

I added the js file in jscript folder and path to the folder

CustomTemplate-jscript-(All the related js file). But now i cant able to give the link the js file or is those files are linked automatically, if yes then i did not the get result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the js files are linked automatically in every page if their name starts with 'jscript_' (e.g. jscript_myscript.js) css files have to start with 'style' in their name (e.g. stylemystyle.css)